# How to run tests in Nemerle project

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, nemerle

How do I run tests which will test my nemerle code. So for example, I've a Calculator class and a CalculatorTests class in a nemerle project. I have already added a reference to nunit using package manager ("install-package nunit"). Now NUnit is available in nemerle project.

After writing following code

```
  [TestFixture]
  class CalculatorTests
  {
        [Test]
        MyTest() : void
        {
            def result = Calculator().Add( 1 );
            Assert.AreEqual( 2, result );
        }
  }
```

I tried to use TestDriven.net visual studio add-in to run the test but couldn't able to. Can someone tell me how to run tests in nemerle or do i have to write code to run all tests when executing a console app?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what happened? I just use NUnit most of the time — it works like with any other .NET language.

Comment: I am getting this error -> Couldn't find test targets. and it displays 0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped.

Comment: I am afraid I don't use Nemerle in Visual Studio, so can't help with that sort of error.

Comment: ncrunch is working fine and running all tests. i think its an issue with TestDriven.net may be?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it caused by NUnit runs under .Net 2.0 runtime. Try to set a runtime version in the NUnit command line.